# Problema com data no spring boot + mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer um findAll no spring boot, pois a data está vindo com 1 dia de atraso.

```
public List<ContaReceber> findAll() {
    return contaReceberRepository.findAll();
}

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meubanco?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo
```

Eu cadastrei uma conta à receber dia 08-11-2019, os dados estão sendo salvo corretamente, ao fazer um findAll, o resultado retorna 07-11-2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,coloque isso no seu springApplication:

```
@PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  }
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Em seu caso, o motivo o qual está retornando a data com 1 dia de diferença é que seu banco de dados está configurado com a data UTC-3 que é a de `America/Sao_Paulo`, que você adicionou na conexão com o banco de dados:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meubanco?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo
```

Apesar de seu banco estar com o UTC-3 que é o correto, sua aplicação não está, e acaba pegando o UTC local, que é UTC-3, mas ao resgatar o dado ele diminui as -3 horas o que faz a data diminuir 1 dia, pois, sua aplicação pensa que a data retornada está em formato UTC, então reduz -3 horas.

Então a melhor solução é a aplicação e o banco de dados estarem configurados com o mesmo fuso, como Melchior Felix dizia, mas no lugar de "UTC", "America/Sao_Paulo".

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    }
}
```